# Need to order each of three colums "lg_ID" 1st, "Starting_pitcher" 2nd, and "Game-Date" third, with Game_Date rows in ascending, sequential order?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sequelpro

I'm having difficulty ordering by "Starting_Pitcher" column for the full range of dates available in the Game_Date column; When I click on "Game_Date" column heading in Sequel Pro with the purpose of ordering any given starting_pitcher results by Game_Date, although dates show up in sequential order, the pitchers listed for those sequential rows of dates are not of one single pitcher. But, when I click "Game_Date" column heading again, the first date listed is now year 1977 (instead of the earliest year of the database which is 1974), and the dates are listed in sequential order for any given starting pitcher (as I'd like them to be).

I would like to be able to show game_dates in sequential order for each starting pitcher starting with the earliest possible Game_Date of this dataset (i.e., 1974-04-04) but need guidance on how to do it.  Below is a screenshot of what it looks like when the Game_Dates are listed in sequential order for any given starting pitcher starting in 1977.

[image]

...And below is what it looks like when, although Game_Dates appear in sequential order starting with 1974-04-04, the Starting_Pitcher field (and lg_ID field for that matter) isn't ordered such that sequential dates are listed for the same starting pitcher (which I would like them to be).

[image]

Can someone offer some guidance on how I can order 1st by Starting_Pitcher and then by lg_ID such that game dates will be presented sequentially in rows (starting with 1974-04-04) for any given starting pitcher; as well as presented sequentially for each of two leagues (lg_ID, AL or NL) such that all of the sequential game dates of starting pitchers will be listed for one league followed by all sequential game dates for starting pitchers in the other league? Please ask me questions to clarify anything if unclear.

Thank you in advance.

Lee

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what your expected result should look like, but I think you want to order your results by Starting_Pitcher first and then by Game_Date? Like so: `ORDER BY Starting_Pitcher, Game_Date`